# Copy Directory - Post Build Event

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

How do I copy some directory from one place to another (not file by file) 
in post build event (whats the comman line??). im using vs 2005 (c++ project)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The commandline is simply a batch script that is executed upon completion of the build. Therefore, you can just use regular Windows shell commands, such as `mkdir`, `copy`, ... To copy whole directories recursively, use `xcopy <src> <dest> /E`.

Answer (score 26):

For more clarification, here is an example that copies a folder called "ApplicationFiles" from the root of your project to the destination (binary) folder:

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)ApplicationFiles" "$(TargetDir)ApplicationFiles" /e /y /i /r
```

Answer (score 16):

Thanks, just what I needed. Options documented here for future reference:

```
/E   Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones. Same as /S /E. May be used to modify /T.

/Y   Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.

/I   If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.

/R   Overwrites read-only files.
```